# Android 10/Q, the MediaStore and MediaPlayer.playFromUri

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediastore, android-10.0

Changes in Android 10 related to the MediaStore seem to now require different code for >=10 and <=9 versions. Having been doing other things for a year I'm back to update an app and having difficulty. My particular problem is I download a music file (all types), store it along with its album art into an internal shared storage directory (Android/media/com.myapp/mydir). I then add it to the MediaStore using the ContentResolver and getting a Uri back. I would then play it using MediaPlayer.playFromUri().

This still works fine on Android <=9 but on 10 MediaPlayer.playFromUri() throws an IO exception. The files are there, the Uri is returned when added to the MediaStore. I've read a few posts here trying to piece together the solution but just can't quite figure it out.

The distilled code for adding to the MediaStore is...

```
        ContentResolver cr = getContext().getContentResolver();
        ContentValues vtrack = new ContentValues();

        vtrack.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, t.getTitle());
        vtrack.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, audiopath);
        vtrack.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST, t.getArtist());
        vtrack.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM, t.getAlbum());
        vtrack.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC, 1);

        Uri u;
        try {
            u = cr.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, vtrack);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code does not store a file to the media store but only some data. And if you do not use the returned uri to open an outputstream to copy your file to the data will be lost to.

Comment: But you could do all much better. Do not first download to that storage directory but use the obtained uri 'u' directly to download your file to.

Comment: It seems the MediaStore is now both a database and a filesystem? This has (prior to 10) been working fine. I understand, if it now has to be copied to the MediaStore, it's more elegant to do it in one step but will that work for <=9 as well?

Comment: Yes. And why didnt you try already?

Comment: You use the DATA volumn only below Q. With Q use RELATIVE_PATH.

Comment: so below Q the DATA field was the full filepath. With Q I write the audio to the MediaStore and set RELATIVE_PATH to what? Also, if I write the audio to the MediaStore below Q what do I set DATA to?

Comment: Relative_path: DCIM/MyFolder or Pictures/MyFiles. DATA to full path of file.

Comment: Had time to play around. Thanks for your help on this. Please add as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative_path: `DCIM/MyFolder` or `Pictures/MyFiles`.

DATA to `full path of file`. –

Comment: For your information _DATA has been deprecated
use  BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
The primary bucket display name of this media item.